# Batch string replace

Tags: php, regex, batch-file, replace

I have a variable like this

```
"Folder With Spaces/filename.ext"
```

When I pass it to my program via PHP's system command, arguments are separated by spaces

```
system("batch.bat Folder With Spaces/filename.ext");
```

So I have it like this

```
system("batch.bat Folder_With_Spaces/filename.ext");
```

Is there a way now that it is back in the batch program to replace the `_`'s with 's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in your batch file:

```
set str=hello_world_try_this
set str=%str:_= %
echo.%str%
```

Answer (score 2):

Just enclose the parameter that has spaces with quotes.

```
system("batch.bat \"Folder With Spaces/filename.ext\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try escapeshellcmd(), like this:

```
$path = escapeshellcmd("Folder With Spaces/filename.ext");  
system("batch.bat \"$path\"");
```

Comment: ... which would do exactly nothing with the string in question.