# Removing spaces from a Variable in batch and replacing with underscore

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a piece of code in which I have to read from a file and use the information to create the folder structure.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims==;" %%x in (input.txt) do (
    if "%%x"=="Proj_name" set %%x=%%y
    if "%%x"=="Source" set %%x=%%y
    if "%%x"=="Language" set %%x=%%y
)
```

The `input.txt` contains data as

```
Proj_name = Cushman & Wakefield
```

So I am trying to create a folder with that name which throws an error since it contains spaces. I have to replace the spaces in it with underscore to make it work. I tried using the following code but it isn't working.

```
set %Project_Name%=%Project_Name:_=%
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch string replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646016/batch-string-replace)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace the spaces by underscores in the `Proj_Name` env variable like this:

```
set Project_Name=%Project_Name: =_%
```

your errors:

1. `set %Project_Name%=` : don't put percent when setting variable or it will be evaluated
2. you replace space by underscore. Can't work with `:_=`